# Errno 24 (too many open files) error on internal sd card android devices

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm currently working on a cool Android app which analyzes and intersects several image files together. Unfortunately I cannot expose more info regarding it.

Anyhow, I've tested it on several devices and at some random situations reached the too many open files condition (Errno 24). This happened on devices which have an internal SD card (like the Samsung Galaxy S3). After rooting the device, I've been able to identify the problem which is caused because the sdcard is mounted as a separate filesystem (pseudo filesystem called FUSE) where the files opened by my app are actually opened by the system process /system/bin/sdcard/.

**This limits all the processes on the device to 1024 file descriptors only** (Files residing on the SD card). *The 1024 file descriptors limit is Android's max open files per process.*

Take for instance a device with 100 apps installed each opening 10 files (database files, properties and the like), the limit is almost reached. Once the limit of 1024 files is crossed, the whole device is useless - apps stop working and so on.

★★ If you find this troubling as I do, please give this open issue your vote ★★
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39002

Comment: Thanks for your post!  I believe I'm hitting the same issue on Samsung Galaxy Nexus.  In my case, there's only one app involved, but it cycles through many photos and eventually dies after the dreaded message "Cannot create epoll instance.  errno=24".  To the best of my knowledge, I'm cleaning up open files, etc., but have not been able to solve it.  Can you provide any more insight on the cause and possible solutions?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a great interview with Android engineer Dan Morrill regarding the use of fuse filesystem in internal SD card devices. Check it out:
http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for this problem. I hope the issue I've opened will solve it in future Android releases.

Answer (score 0):

This sure does explain the problems I've been having with several Bittorrent clients. The files download and appear to be present on the external SD card, but they're not usable, and when I force a recheck of the downloaded data, it shows missing or corrupted pieces.

For weeks, I was blaming the Torrent swarm (bad peers?), the SD card itself (defective? Not seated?), or KitKat (nothing to do with the somewhat annoying new restrictions).

Every torrent open seems to associate a file handle and a network socket with each peer... 10 torrents running, 10 peers each; no problem. But 10 torrents open, some of which may connect to 50 peers if the swarm is fast, and my poor little phone must have smashed hard into the file handle ceiling. And that's before I do anything else at all with the SD card!

Users of Android Torrent clients would naturally want to use external SD cards...
- large files
- separate filesystem makes me feel safer using an HTTP server to transfer the data to any other computer
- download a Linux distro and be able to pop it right into the SD card slot!

The workaround that I've devised - and it seems to work so far - is to keep the active Torrents in the main storage and transfer them to the SD card once they're done writing. This way I do avoid corrupting the data as it appears on my SD card. Flud (Google Play) is unobtrusive, reliable, and has the option to move completed Torrents to a new location.